# Why isn't the Illuminator badge tracked in the Moderator Elections?

Tags: discussion, badges, moderator-election

While casting my votes in the final phase of the elections, I just realized that the [Illuminator](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator) badge is not included in the Editing badge count:

[image]

As you can see, however, its predecessors ([Explainer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4368/explainer) and [Refiner](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4369/refiner)) *are* included. Why isn't the Illuminator badge included?

Comment: So very few people have the badge that it'd probably just serve to change the highest 'normal' score from 40/40 to 40/41

Comment: Best guess:  Because only 24 people have it?

Comment: Cause it would make Martijn look **even** better than the rest of the candidates.

Comment: @TimLewis Martijn makes Martijn look better than the rest of the candidates.

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been downvoted... it's not really suggesting an idea; it's just asking *why* it's not included...

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables One of those 24 people is a candidate for moderator. Surely that's a huge plus for him? Isn't that the entire point of including the 20 badges in the score?

Comment: @TylerH don't take it personally, downvotes on meta don't count for anything

Comment: @meagar Sure, I'm aware of how it works/that they're meant to show disagreement rather than perceived low quality. I'm just a bit bemused since this is just a very basic question of why something is the case :-P

Comment: @TylerH - because it's so above-and-beyond the norm, it would pretty much knock everyone else *down* a point.  Maybe there could be an "Exemplary accomplishments" or "OMGWTF why aren't you already a mod?" section that lists such achievements.  Kinda like an extra gold star sticker or something.

Comment: @TylerH: and as much as I'd love to show of all my badges, does that tell you anything more about my suitability to moderate over and above the other two badges? :-)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I suppose that's true; gold badges are supposed to be for above-and-beyond, exemplary actions. Though that's hopefully what we hold moderators to, and other gold badges *are* included (Electorate, Marshal, Steward, Copy Editor), though I agree Illuminator is probably more extraordinary than those. Perhaps an election or two down the road, other badges will be included as their award rate rises

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure, every badge is more information :-) But along the same lines I mentioned in my most previous comment, I suppose a badge about editing questions you've *also answered* is not wholly tied to moderation, and therefore a little unbiased toward moderators who also answer questions on Main vs. those who just spend their time moderating Main. But, that's the kind of info I was looking for in answers to this question, after all!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because it is *far harder to reach*. There are only 24 people *on the site* that have managed to earn the badge.

Besides, moderation isn't all about answering loads of questions; it is about knowing about the whole system and what kinds of problems you need to deal with as a moderator. And that's what the candidate score is trying to tell you: an easy to understand ability checklist.

As such, the Explainer and Refiner badges are nice indicators that the candidates not only know how to answer, but how to improve the questions as well, without demanding that they created the 500 answers that were up voted and where the corresponding question was edited required for that gold badge.